# what could I use to wrapp a SSH server for a Telnet client

Tags: java, ssh, telnet, putty, netcat

In my case, the server has been secured by passing all console access to SSH, 
but the client console must remain with Telnet because it is integrated in an application that can't be modified.
Due to incompatibility of protocols I imagine a "proxy" service in order to manage the SSH protocol including authentication and encryption decoding, 
that would redirect the shell dialog in plain-text to a local socket (no file transfer or other feature needed).
Any advice about solution based on Windows utility (putty, netcat ...) or JEE service dev will be welcome.
I can only install something on the Windows client system.
Thx

Comment: So your ultimate goal is essentially to make this legacy Java app use SSH instead of Telnet?

Comment: yes indeed, this case talk to you?

Comment: Are you positive that you can't modify the existing system? You could investigate the classes that handle the Telnet operations then "overwrite" them with compatible classes using SSH instead. You can do this by creating your own classes that have the same qualified name and interface (but your own SSH implementations), compiling them, and giving them  precedence on the classpath so they get used in place of the originals causing the application  to use SSH. You don't have to actually replace anything of the original JAR, you just tell it to use some custom classes instead.

Comment: Thx for reply. Sure it would be the best solution, but unfortunatly this application is not mine, I have no sources nor right to modify, that's the reason why I want to insert some "connector".
this small service would be relatively easy to do but I was hoping that this case would be sufficiently widespread that some tools already exist without having to develop.

Comment: So the local machine sends SSH to a remote server, the server receives SSH but requires Telnet for the console app, so you need to convert the SSH to Telnet? Or does the Telnet come in somewhere else?

Comment: Hi xtratic, yes I need to translate protocol, the server is exclusively SSH and the client console can't support SSH, so I need to insert an adapter, something like this
[local_telnet_console_client]--<plaintext_console_dialog>--[local_telnet_svc_to_ssh_client_I_need]--<encrypted_console_dialog>--[remote_ssh_serv]